# Sharepoint 2013 Really Slow

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have been working with Sharepoint 2013 in our small office. However, i notice the sharepoint is very slow. Not always slow. Intermittent slow. When i first access the page it will take long for the page to appears. Then after that will be okay again. Then after a while when i click a link, the page will load very slow again and so on. Is sharepoint 2013 supposed to be like this?

Comment: Do you reboot your servers often? Do the server have the minimum requirements to run SharePoint? Have you modified your CSS? Do you have the minimal download feature activated?

Comment: What is the configuration of your Sharepoint farm and how many users using this?

Comment: No SharePoint is not supposed to be like that, make sure you have sufficient resources (like memory, disk and CPU). You could have a longer loading time on the first requests in the morning though (SharePoint does a recycle of its Application pools at night)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slowness of sharePoint due to many factors.

- you dont have enough hardware resources(CPU , RAM)
- You have heavy customization
- SQL Server may be
- Have Antivirus on the servers
- Network causing the slowness
- custom queris to database
- large List or libraries

How we can figured out and fixed it.

- I am big fan of [Developer Dashbaord](http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/developer-dashboard-in-sharepoint-2013.html), this will give the break down  of time during the page load. On which part it spend how much time.
- [Config the perfmon on the SharePoint Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758658%28v=office.15%29.aspx) & SQL to Identify the bottle neck.
- Monitor the IIS logs, ULS logs and Event Logs.

You can avoid the issue.

- Confgure the different Cache avaiable in sharepoint i.e [Output cache, object cache, and anonymous search results cache](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee424404%28v=office.15%29.aspx#section4), [Disk Based Blob cache](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee424404%28v=office.15%29.aspx#Section1)
- take advantage of [Bit Rate Throttling](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee424404%28v=office.15%29.aspx#Section2)
- consider the [upload file size](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee424404%28v=office.15%29.aspx#Section3) limit as this may cause big hit on performance.
- [exclude sharepoint directories for antivirus scan](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/952167)
- Distributed Cache
- Use the [warm up script](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=404) to avoid slowness of 1st time page load

Answer (score 1):

Along with what others have said, there could be a secret culprit that I know I ran into when I had the same things happen to me.  If you have any workflows associated with your site, check how many items are currently running.  When I first started sharepoint, I assumed that if a workflow is waiting, it wouldn't take up too much resource allocation with the CPU, but every running workflow takes its toll.  I had about 100 running workflows, and had to manually stop each one to fix the problem.  If these workflows have loops that don't terminate, that would be even worse.

Again, just check how many workflows are running on your site, then check server CPU use and thread # to determine what is slowing everything down.

And, like your problem, when the server was shut off, and turned back on again, everything worked great.  But after an hour or so, it would go back to being painfully slow.

Answer (score 1):

Only to add: Views with large numbers of items rendered by JavaScript on the client can be slow, too. Like when you use a lot of Client-Side Rendering transformations or set Item Limit to something like 100 or more items per page, or when you edit a long list using JSGrid.